# How to compute $H^1(\Sigma_g-\{p\})$ using Mayer-Vietoris?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

How can I find, using Mayer-Vietoris, $H^1(\Sigma_g-\{p\})$, where $\Sigma_g$ is a genus $g$ surface?

Comment: The space $\Sigma_g = \{p\}$ deformation-retracts onto a wedge of $g$ circles. Use Mayer-Vietoris on a wedge of two circles and then proceed by induction on genus.

Comment: @Neal, I'm pretty sure it retracts onto a wedge of $2g$ circles.

Comment: @Neal, for using induction I'll have to compute the cohomology of $\mathbb T^2-\{p, q\}$, for $p, q\in\mathbb T^2$ distinct, and I don't know to do it..

Comment: @PiotrPstragowski Yes indeed it does, thank you.

Comment: @PtF why are you computing cohomology of $\mathbb{T}^2$ minus two points? Just take away one point, deformation retract onto a wedge of two circles, and the compute the homology and cohomology groups of a wedge of two circles. You can do this by hand or you can use Mayer-Vietoris.

Answer (score 2):

The space $\Sigma_g - \{p\}$ deformation-retracts onto a wedge of $2g$ circles, so it suffices to compute cohomology of $\vee_{2g}\mathbb{S}^1$. This can be done quickly by hand, but since the exercise asks you to use Mayer-Vietoris, here's a sketch how to do it in the case of a punctured torus.

Let $X = \mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1$, $A$ and $B$ each be one of the circles, and $A\cap B$ be the wedge point. Use Mayer-Vietoris to relate $H^i(A)$, $H^i(B)$, and $H^1(A\cap B)$ to $H^i(X) \cong H^i(\Sigma_g)$; the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence for cohomology is
$$0\to H^0(X)\to H^0(A)\oplus H^0(B)\to H^0(A\cap B)\to H^1(X)\to H^1(A)\oplus H^1(B)\to H^1(A\cap B)$$

The basic idea will be to exploit that the map $H^1(X)\to H^1(A)\oplus H^1(B)$ is an epimorphism.

Having computed $H^1(\Sigma_1-\{p\})$, proceed by induction: $\Sigma_g-\{p\}$ deformation retracts onto a wedge of $2g$ circles, which is a bouquet of $2g-2$ circles with two more wedged on. So let $A = \vee_{2g-2}\mathbb{S}^1 \cong (\Sigma_{g-1}-\{p\})$ and $B = \mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1\cong (\Sigma_1-\{p\})$ and use Mayer-Vietoris again.

---

Just for fun, here's how to do it by hand. Since $\pi_1$ of a wedge of $n$ circles is free on $n$ generators and $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1$, we know that $H_1$ of a wedge of $n$ circles is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Use the relationship between $H^1$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1,\mathbb{Z})$ to find $H^1$.